# how to get rid of the "tablesorter-header-inner" div in tablesorter 2

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

since tablesorter is upgraded to version 2, it starts adding an extra div with class "tablesorter-header-inner" to every tr after sorting. It screws up a lot of stuff in my project.

I am just wondering if there is a way to avoid adding these extra div.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you have having issues with? How exactly is it that it "screws up a lot of stuff"? What does that mean?

Comment: basically, I had some jquery callback functions attached on the DOMs inside th, and I believe the "tablesorter-header-inner" div is added by making a clone of those DOMS, remove the original ones and put the clones inside the tablesorter-header-inner. All the callback functions were lost. If I replace the callbacks with dynamic callbacks, there will be some duplication problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/). If that is the case, just set the [`headerTemplate` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#headertemplate) to an empty string (`''`) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/5122/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        headerTemplate: ''
    });
});
```

The reason it was added was because in older versions of Firefox, the table cell could not have a `position` definition applied to it. That has since been resolved (I'm pretty sure), so the "tablesorter-header-inner" isn't necessary any more.

Comment: This answer helped me too:) Thank you